Droidscript HttpRequest - Unable to access Cookie value
I'm currently making an HTTP request using DroidScript, and I'm encountering some problems.
var headers = "Cookie=name=value"

http = app.HttpRequest("GET", http://localhost/, null, null, callback,headers);
http.send(null);

The PHP Server index.php
<?php
   foreach(getallheaders() as $header => $val){
       echo "<h5>$header => $val<h5/>";
   }
?>

The HTTP response.
Accept-Charset => UTF-8
Cookie => name
Connection => Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding => gzip

I tried using the escape character.
var headers = "Cookie=name%3Dvalue"; 
var headers = "Cookie=name\x3Dvalue"; 

The result is the same.
The cookie name is all I can get, not the value.
